# Adapter in recycler view duplicate images after scrolling View. KOTLIN

Tags: android, parsing, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a basically all in one layout which has everything needed for my app's main feed. All variable items (images, video thumbnails.. Etc.) This layout creates from fragment which have a list of items that contains articles from one site and from that fragment I pass URL from which I parse information in my newsDetailsParser. In some views where I don't have a lot of text the images isn't duplicates , but in others that have a lot of text every time I scroll the screen from top to bottom or backwards it duplicates. And duplicates only image , any other item like text , title , subTitle I see correctly. I don't know why this is happening and I need any help.

[Video with my problem](https://youtu.be/JBjJPFrEV6s)

[This project on GitHub](https://github.com/Akirinoshi/Book_of_recipes)

Maybe you have advise how to off updating(onScroll or onClick , I don't know which exactly) of this view after first open?

This image is article with some rows of text and when I scroll it all is ok

[article with a few text after scrolling(all is ok)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEXZ3.png)

But this happens when I try to scroll article with more text

[before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0IFM.jpg)

[after a few scrolls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGpHA.jpg)

Function from which I start this intent

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener { item: Item<GroupieViewHolder>, view ->
                    val newsAdapter = item as NewsAdapter

                    val intent = Intent(view.context, NewsDetails::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("refUrl", newsAdapter.getRef())
                    startActivity(view.context, intent, intent.extras)
                }
```

Item class

```
class NewsDetailsItem(val title: String, var imgRef: String,
                  val subTitle: String, val text: String,
                  val videoRef: String, val detailsName: String,
                  val detailsString: String, val titleText : String) {
constructor() : this("","","","","", "","","")
```

}

Main class

```
class NewsDetails : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity_news_details)
    var refUrl: String? = intent.extras?.getString("refUrl")
    intent.extras?.clear()

    val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()

    adapter.add(NewsDetailsAdapter(NewsDetailsItem("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")))

    recycler_view_news_details.adapter = adapter

    NewsDetailsParser.fetchData(refUrl, recycler_view_news_details)
}
}
```

Class Parser

```
class NewsDetailsParser {
companion object {
    fun fetchData(refUrl: String?, recycler_view_news_details: RecyclerView) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            try {
                val document = Jsoup.connect(refUrl).get()
                val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
                val elementHeader = document.select("div[class=article-page__header]")
                val elementPagePoster = document.select("div[class=article-page__poster]")
                val elementLeftAside = document.getElementsByClass("staff__item")
                var elementContent1 = document.select("div[class=introduction]")
                elementContent1 = elementContent1.select("p")
                val elementContent2 = document.select("div[class=article-page__article layout__content-col]")

                println("ELEMENT 1 : $elementContent1")
                //println("ELEMENT 2 : $elementContent2")

                for(i in 0 until elementHeader.size) {
                    val title = elementHeader
                        .select("h1")
                        .eq(i)
                        .text()

                    val subTitle = elementHeader
                        .select("p")
                        .eq(i)
                        .text()

                    adapter.add(NewsDetailsAdapter(NewsDetailsItem(title, "", "", "", "", "", "", "")))
                    adapter.add(NewsDetailsAdapter(NewsDetailsItem("", "", subTitle, "", "", "", "", "")))
                }

                for(i in 0 until elementPagePoster.size) {
                    var imgRef = elementPagePoster
                        .select("img")
                        .attr("srcset")

                    imgRef = imgRef.dropLast(3)

                    adapter.add(NewsDetailsAdapter(NewsDetailsItem("", imgRef, "", "", "", "", "", "")))
                }

                for(i in 0 until elementLeftAside.size) {
                    var detailsName = elementLeftAside[i]
                        .select("span[class=position uppercase]")
                        .text()


                    var detailsString = elementLeftAside[i]
                        .select("span")
                        .not("span[class=position uppercase]")
                        .text()

                    adapter.add(NewsDetailsAdapter(NewsDetailsItem("", "", "", "", "", detailsName, "", "")))
                    adapter.add(NewsDetailsAdapter(NewsDetailsItem("", "", "", "", "", "", detailsString, "")))
                }

                for(i in 0 until elementContent1.size) {
                    val text = elementContent1
                        .select("p")
                        .eq(i)
                        .text()

                    adapter.add(NewsDetailsAdapter(NewsDetailsItem("", "", "", text, "", "", "", "")))
                }


                GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    recycler_view_news_details.adapter = adapter
                }
            } catch (e : IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Class Adapter

```
class NewsDetailsAdapter(private val newsDetailsItem: NewsDetailsItem) : Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //title
    viewHolder.itemView.row_title_news_details_item.text = newsDetailsItem.title
    //subTitle
    viewHolder.itemView.row_subTitle_news_details_item.text = newsDetailsItem.subTitle
    //image
    if(newsDetailsItem.imgRef != "") {
        Picasso.get().load(newsDetailsItem.imgRef).into(viewHolder.itemView.row_img_news_details_item)
    }
    //detailsName
    viewHolder.itemView.row_left_aside_title_news_details_name_item.text = newsDetailsItem.detailsName
    //detailsString
    viewHolder.itemView.row_left_aside_title_news_details_string_item.text = newsDetailsItem.detailsString
    //text
    viewHolder.itemView.row_text_news_details_item.text = "      ${newsDetailsItem.text}"
}

override fun getLayout(): Int {
    return R.layout.news_details_item
}
}
```

xml layout of item :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_img_news_details_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_title_news_details_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/black"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_subTitle_news_details_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/row_left_aside_title_news_details_name_item"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="start"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:text=""
android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_left_aside_title_news_details_string_item"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_text_title_news_details_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_text_news_details_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout of this intent (xml) :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_news_details">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_news_details"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `RecyclerView` is recycling viewholders as you scroll which means one ViewHolder will undergo multiple `onBindViewHolder` calls. Following your `if(newsDetailsItem.imgRef != "") { /* setting up image with Picasso */}` you must have an `else` case that will set image to default/null. Right now you're leaking image of whatever item viewholder was bound to before.

Comment: @Pawel , tnx , I very appreciate for your answer , but can you also say how to write this this , because I know a few variants like this `Picasso.get().load("google.com").into(viewHolder.itemView.row_img_news_details_item)` but I think that there is a much better variant of this code

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem ? If yes, please share the answer. I'm also facing the same problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue, I solved it by inserting an image in every row in onBindViewHolder. I'm not sure if it is a cache problem, but I will have duplicate images (not text) if I only set an image in 1 row and do nothing with the ImageView in other rows.